# In what order should I add these JavaScript file references for jQuery datatables editor to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I currently have JavaScript file references in this order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/editor.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/editor.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/editor.foundation.min.js"></script>
```

However, I see the following two errors in the console of my browser's developer tools. I believe the order in which I have included these files is wrong. Could you please tell me the right order?

[image]

The first error is in the source file `editor.jquery.ui.min.js` and the second one is in `dataTables.editor.min.js`.

Comment: Where's your base jQueryUI import?  That's separate from jQuery itself.

Comment: I didn't include it in the question. It's right at the top. I am updating the question with it.

Comment: On a second look, I *did* include it in the original question. It's right at the top. :-)

Comment: OK. I'm pretty sure you need jQuery before jQueryUI. No, that's **jQuery**. The jQuery and jQueryUI libraries are two separate things.

Comment: datatables editor is likely dependent on datatables so lily need to switch those

Answer (score 1):

According to [DataTables - jQuery UI example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryui.html), you need to load JS files in the following order:

```js
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/buttons.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/datatables/editor.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
```

You were missing `jquery-ui.js`, and the order of some libraries were incorrect. Also you don't need `editor.bootstrap.min.js` and `editor.foundation.min.js` if you use jQuery UI styling.

Answer (score 0):

The [download](https://datatables.net/download/) page offers a customized import order easily. Just check the options you are using, and it will lay out the whole css and js import order